# How to query database every X minutes

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka, actor, fsm

I want to monitor our order process via akka and scala and want to build an actor system.
the messages that come from the webshop are stored in a mongoDB and are stored in 4 different collections.
each collections needs an own FSM, because the order has different states in each collection (e.g. collection1=payment, collection2=delivery, ...)

my question is how to set up this whole actor system.
especially I need to know how I deal with the mongoDB, because I need to see if there are new entries in the database every X minutes. This query should be executed by an Actor, which sends its messages to FSMs. How can I achieve that?

I didn't really find something on Google (or I just don't know WHAT to google :/ )

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

akka has a scheduler. you could use it to do the query every X time: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/scheduler.html

Another (ugly) solution would be to do an infinite loop with thread sleep

Comment: okay, that is a good point :)
do you know how I can make sure to only get the added documents since the last query?